# How Strip path from http request URL into Rewrite or Redirect URL for Azure CDN Standard Rules?

Tags: azure, redirect, url-rewriting, azure-cdn

Hello and thanks for stopping by!

I want to forward to a different domain an incoming Http request into an Azure Microsoft CDN (standard rules), forward it either with url redirect or url rewrite - example:

Incoming http request url into cdn: https://cdn-domain.com/PATH-1

URL Redirect / Rewrite to: https://newdomain.com/SUBPATH/PATH-1/

I know what newdomain.com and SUBPATH are. I need to strip PATH-1 from the url request, is this possible? If not, the URL Rewrite rules may be able to do it with *preserved unmatched path* option but in this case what is the source pattern and destination regex to achieve the above url please?

[image]

I tried URL_Rewrite rule regex as below but rewritten url misses SUBPATH:

Rewrite Source pattern: /cdn-domain.com/(.*)

Rewrite Destination: /newdomain.com/SUBPATH/{R:1}

Cheers